# eclipse - how to create a java project for multiple developers( github)

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I would like to know how to configure an eclipse java(java application - OSX ) project -

```
1) multiple developers will contribute to the project
2) SCM will be git (at github)
```

My requirement is that when a new developer joins the project, he should be able to 
clone the project and should be able to compile the project in his eclipse in a few minutes.

I am very new to eclipse, if my question is very basic, forgive me ...
any link to existing tutorial for this also will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Consider using some kind of dependency manager like maven as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is sufficiently simple (one or a few Eclipse projects, no dependencies outside of the project's workspace, no weird compiler settings or nonstandard Eclipse plugins) - you don't really need to do much.  Commit the entire project directory, including the .project and .classpath files but excluding any output directories (e.g. bin/).   Other developers can then just clone and tell Eclipse to import an existing project into their workspace, and be off to the races.  EGit provides passable integration of Git into the IDE, but isn't really necessary (and I personally frequently drop to the command-line Git client for complicated merges, etc.)

Comment: if I check in classpath and .project, those will have paths that are relevant only for my machine. How can I solve this?

Comment: Typically they wouldn't - at least, not if your dependencies are all in a project in your workspace; for in-project stuff, Eclipse should be using relative paths.  If you've got dependencies that aren't, then look into using Maven or some other dependency manager to supply those.

Comment: thanks Sbodd for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are various plugins available for Eclipse to augment its functionality. Egit seems to be the plugin you are looking for.

http://eclipse.org/egit/

A more detailed tutorial of how to integrate git with an Eclipse project can be found here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html

However the plugin is only for ease of use. With a little mastery of the command line, even without the plugin, cloning the project and starting to work with it should be trivial, no matter what IDE you are choosing to go with.